# who to wrap callbacks with a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Lets say I have a given function **I can not change** which has a callback function:

```
markAsRead(item_id,function(result){console.log(result)})
```

How can I wrap that function with a promise so I could know which item_id was returned? Something like this:

```
markRead(item_id).then(function(result)
    {
      emailOwner(result)
    },
    function(result)
    {
      emailSystem(result)
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting this promise from, and how would it be resolved ?

Answer (score 3):

```
function markRead(item_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      markAsRead(item_id,function(result){
          if (/* result is OK */) {
            resolve(result);
          }
          else {
            reject(result);
          }
      })
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, just what I needed!